# Correlation in the shape of two lines

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation

The two groups of lines below each have a correlation close to 1 but they have very different shapes.  Let’s say each represents the changes in price of gold and silver at different times - there is undoubtedly different information between the two.

[image]

What I’m wondering is how to determine how closely the shape of one line reflects the shape of the other.  In a real example, the lines would have peaks and valleys, so slope alone is not enough.  I think I could find the cumulative differences between the lines at various points in time and somehow measure that against the standard deviation of one or both of the lines, but there has to be a standardized way to do this.

Also not ruling out the possibility that I’m missing something completely obvious.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update:**

To better illustrate using slightly more realistic examples for a financial time series, the points of the two segments in Chart C below have a correlation of 1.  The points of the segments in Chart D still have a very high correlation, but it is less than 1, but if each pair of segments comes from the same dataset, I would argue that the segments in Chart D are more statistically similar than the segments in Chart C after accounting for a known standard deviation, which would be the same for both segments in each chart.  I think the eye test also confirms that.

Again, I'm comparing different segments within the same time series for similarity.

Maybe said differently, if I picked a few hundred pairs of segments in a random time series, and took the sum of absolute percentage differences (for the purpose of comparison the initial point in a segment would always be zero and the subsequent points expressed as a +/- percentage) for each point of each pair of segments, the segments in Chart D would likely be among the lowest pairs in terms of cumulative absolute percentage difference.  And maybe that’s all I need to do.

---

**Chart C:**

[image]

**Chart D:**

[image]

Comment: It might help if you gave us an example that's closer to the actual kinds of curves/sequences you're trying to compare. But my initial reaction to the question as currently stated is that dynamic time warping might be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Comment: This is for a trading strategy that involves identifying historical segments of a time series that closely mirror the most recent segment of the same length of time.  Does that help?  Just from that quick read, Dynamic Time Warping gets to the broad point but there should be no warping.

Comment: Geometrically, all lines have the same shape.  This leaves us wondering (1) what exactly do you mean by "shape" and (2) what you are hoping a comparison of shapes will accomplish in your study.  Please provide this information in your question.

Comment: Speaking of which, the question should probably be retitled to ask about "curves" instead of lines, since you're not actually interested in lines at all

Comment: I just updated the question.  I thought this would be more straightforward so I thought I could get away with explaining it in terms of straight lines, which was a lot easier freehand.  When I said "lines," I was referring to a line chart for visualization purposes, but I'm really referring to points.  In the update, I used the term "segments" rather than lines for clarity.

Comment: If the curves are time series, then won't a standard time series analysis give you what you want? Autocorrelation over time with detrending of whatever variety you choose?

Comment: @JakeWestfall DTW is fascinating. Thanks for sharing that link. There are implementations for both Python and R available: https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/#welcome-to-the-dynamic-time-warp-suite